# Angular Validation ng messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on AngualarJS validations, but what I'm trying to achieve doesn't work with ng-messages.

For example I want the messages to appear after the input fields had been $touched or invalid, this way when the user first uses the input fields he doesn't receive an error message, only when he goes to other input. Here is my code:

```
<div ng-messages="form.company_name.$invalid && form.company_name.$touched">
    <p ng-message="minlength">Your name is too short.</p>
    <p ng-message="maxlength">Your name is too long.</p>
    <p ng-message="required">Your name is required.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

With some more research, I found the solution:

```
<div ng-messages="form.company_name.$error"
     ng-if="form.company_name.$touched">
```